# Citrix Receiver & Midori

Tags: pi-2

I need help with getting Citrix receiver (xenapp) to work with the Midori browser. I cannot download the .ica file from the client's web page. How can I do this?

Comment: What distro and version are you using? Have you tried installing and using iceweasel?

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 15.04 (old i know but i need it) and in ubuntu iceweasel is Firefox but its slow, i installed midori and its faster, only problem im stuck at is using midori on our Xenapp platform